# Angular event (ng-keydown) memory leaking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, memory-leaks, dom-events

I'm creating an input in which if you hold key "up" or "down", it increments or decrements the number value in that input.

For key event, I'm using ng-keydown directive which updates the $scope.value which is bound (ng-bind) to the input itself.

The problem is holding the key gets slower and slower the longer I hold it.

[I've recreated a basic version in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3468/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = 9;
    $scope.updown = function($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode == 40) $scope.number -= 1;
        else if ($event.keyCode == 38) $scope.number += 1;
}   }
```

It doesn't get *as* slow as my own implementation, which has some other stuff to it too, but I've timeline'd its (jsfiddle's) memory-leak in chrome dev tools to reveal the same pattern.

[image]

And it's not just ng-keydown, but other events also are misbehaving like this ([mousewheel](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-mousewheel))

What's going on and how could I avoid this?

---

**edit** For comparison, [this is how chrome natively handles the `<input type='number'>`!](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3469/)

[image]

Comment: this is interesting, but for me the memory drops back to normal after a bit. It just looks like garbage collection is delayed for a while until it hits some point and is triggered. Can you revise your example to show how it would lag performance?

Comment: If you force garbage collection a couple of times between inputting, does it drop to the same level each time?

Comment: I'm not seeing the same memory usage pattern as your displaying nor is the responsiveness slowing the longer I hold it. I'm seeing the same pattern as Matthew Foscarini.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I've added how chrome natively handles similar thing.

Comment: @marck responsiveness slowing isn't noticeable in this simple example but it's there. Shouldn't spikes alone tell us that there indeed is a performance issue here?

Comment: It should be expected that Chrome would handle it much more efficiently using a native input type vs. a JS implementation. If your example doesn't demonstrate the problem are you able to post something more akin to what you're working with? Also, have you tried throttling the event handler a bit?

Comment: Everytime angular handles an event. It has to perform a digest cycle for the current scope, and propagate up the scope stack. This is repeated until no watchers indicate any more changes. I would assume this results in the creation of a lot of JS objects. When the digest exists the browser triggers the next event, and this process repeats. You can't force GC in javascript. So I don't know if there is much you can do. I have read that if you use jQuery events with Angular there is the risk that event bindings cause DOM elements to persist that should be removed, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Use a debounce function (grab it out of underscore/lodash). It basically allows you to limit the rate at which a function can fire. I'm using it in a module of mine to allow limiting on window resize: https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/ng-FitText.js/blob/master/ng-FitText.js#L55

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this issue that helped me is adding a debounce to input field. It makes Angular process data in intervals which results in more fluid UX.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="number" ng-model-options="{ debounce:500 }">
```

You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions